# Running a file via the interpreter changes current directory?

Tags: python, pythonpath

When I try to `$> python ./tools/test.py`  I get an import error that I cannot import a module that exists in the directory from which I am invoking python.  However, I can import this module, `$> python -c "import mod"` works.

I'm relying on the fact that `./` is (in effect) on the PYTHONPATH.

What is python doing to the python path when I run the interpreter on a script that exists in a different directory?  Is there a way to "lock" the current working directory so that I can get the import to work?

My setup:

`./mod.py`  :

```
x = 5     # just for demonstration purposes
```

`./tools/test.py` :

```
from mod import x
# ... snip ... actual content
```

I am invoking python from the directory that contains `mod.py` and `tools/`:

```
$> python -c "from mod import x"      # works fine
$> python tools/test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "tools/test.py", line 1, in <module>
from mod import x
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod'
```

Note that the current directory, which contains `mod.py` and `tools` is **not** on my PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm relying on the fact that `./` is (in effect) on the PYTHONPATH.

It's not. It's not on `PYTHONPATH`, and it's not on `sys.path`. When you run a script by file path, it's the *script's* directory that gets added to `sys.path`. You can see what gets added to `sys.path` for each way of specifying a program to run in the [Python command line docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html).